# How to use OIDC in Jakarta EE?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, openid-connect

I have the requirement to protect my existing Jakarta EE application with an OpenID provider in one of many different environments.

When searching about this topic you will find the `@OpenIdAuthenticationDefinition` defined by Payara and [explained in this blog](https://blog.payara.fish/how-to-use-openidconnect-with-payara-platform-to-achieve-single-sign-on) and also the new annotation `@OpenIdAuthenticationMechanismDefinition`  [introduced in Jakrata EE10](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/security/enterprise/authentication/mechanism/http/openidauthenticationmechanismdefinition).

```
@OpenIdAuthenticationDefinition(
       providerURI = "https://sample-openid-server.com",
       clientId = "...",
       clientSecret = "...",
       redirectURI = "${baseURL}/callback",
       ...)
public class MySecureBean {

}
```

But I did not understand the concept behind it. I know OpenID, it is the annotation which confuses me. So my first question is:

Does the `@OpenIdAuthenticationDefinition` mean that I have to annotate each of my CDI and EJB code using the JakaraEE security API? This would mean I have to rewrite many classes and third party libraries in my application?

The second question is more a conceptional about the design of my application:

Why should I pollute my code with an annotation that binds my code to a specific proprietary security layer?
It is one of the core concepts of Jakrata EE to write application code against the specification and not one specific implementation. For example you implement your data layer against JPA and not against a concrete Database Vendor like Oracle or PostgreSQL. This is true for all the other cross functions aspects like directory lookups, messaging or even the security.

So the annotation looks to me like one step forward and two steps back. Or did I miss something?

On the other hand, if it is sufficient to use the `@OpenIdAuthenticationDefinition` annotation just in one application scoped CDI bean to propagate the user credentials to all other components in my application and libraries using the security API, why is there not a general open source implementation of such a OpenID library?

Comment: I share your concerns about the annotation and application design. Nevertheless, you may be able to factor the modules of your application in such a way that the component containing this annotation is an implementation detail, specific to the deployment. And mitigate at least a part of the ugliness. This is just a very generic thought :)

Comment: Yes I exactly do this at the moment. Depending on Maven profiles I add different libraries with custom OIDC definitions. This works but it is not very elegant in compare the the rest of the Jakrata EE API which its clear separation between application and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be more configuration needed than a simple annotated CDI bean.  Yes, you only have to annotate one.  As we are told Jakarta 10+ just picks it up and it just works.

After working with this for about a week I have gotten so far as to see this error:

```
...
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jakarta.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigProvider.getServerAuthConfig(String, String, javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler)" because "authConfigProvider" is null
...
```

Now, this is something that seems to be talked about but as of today I have yet to find a good example to get it to work as I am clueless on how to resolve this error.

All the examples I have found use: securityContext.authenticate(request, response, new AuthenticationParameters());

and that is where I get the error.  Wish there was a good concrete example someplace where it is running on a JakartaEE container in an app using Jakarta Faces.  There are quite a few that use Servlets.

Comment: I was trying this with TOMEE but as of this minute TOMEE does not yet support Jakarta EE 10: https://x.com/arjan_tijms/status/1751297432225190075?s=20